# Como crear una lista de los argumentos de una función en Python si la librería esta escrita en C?

Tags: python, c

Para saber los parámetros de una función en Python se puede hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
def patata(x, y):
    return x+y

import inspect
X=list(inspect.signature(patata).parameters.keys())
print(X)
[X, Y]
```

Tengo una librería llamada talib y quisiera crear una lista con los parámetros que tiene,intente los siguiente.

```
import talib
import inspect
X=list(inspect.signature(talib.ACOS).parameters.keys())

ValueError: no signature found for builtin <built-in function ACOS>
```

Buscando sobre el problema encontré lo siguiente:

The challenge with C functions is that this becomes *additional* metadata that somehow needs to be provided to the method and function creation process. None of our APIs are set up to accept that information (and obviously no code is set up to provide it, either).

What might be nice is a way to graft the signature information from a Python implementation onto a C implementation (which would be quite straightforward given PEP 362 and a writable **signature** slot in the C objects).

The other virtue of this approach is that the Python metadata will be testable, so it doesn't run the same risk of getting out of date that manually maintained metadata at the C level does. It would work naturally for C acceleration modules, and wouldn't be any more effort to add for pure C code than direct annotations at the C level would be.

Pero de hay si no se como seguir.

Comment: podrias traducir la parte en ingles, y poner la referencia a la misma?

Comment: @gbianchi Sale de [aquí](https://bugs.python.org/issue1748064)